# Why does my port forward for my http server on 80 not work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver

I'm a hobbyist programmer, and I've got a website I'd like to host myself. However, I'm very much a begginer at networking so I apologize in advanced if my mistake is something obvious.

I've gone ahead and installed Apache Webserver on my Raspberry Pi. I've tested connecting to the site with chrome using the local ipv4 address, and that works fine.

In order to make it public, I attempted to port forward port 80 (what I understand to be the standard port for http). I also set up a DNS address at http://ashwingupta.mynetgear.com. When I enter this address on my wifi network or enter my public ipv4, I can connect to the website just fine. However, if I go on any other network, I can't connect to my website. I assume this is a result of incorrect port forwarding of 80.

I have other ports forwarded that work just fine, including SSH and Remote Desktop ports to my pi. Given this, the problem doesn't seem to lie in the raspberry pi or the router forwarding in general. I believe this is specific to port 80.

My forwarding setup:
[image]

**What is going on and how can I fix it?**

Note:

-I'm forwarding as a TCP port, I believe that is what the web uses

-My router is a Nighthawk R7000

Comment: You need something other than a subdomain of a Netgear website.  Most consumer ISP prohibit port 80 inbound traffic

Comment: @Ramhound why? Btw, I've also tried connecting using my public ipv4 and this other DNS I set up (http://ashwingupta9.ddns.net/) and that didn't work.

Comment: Well your domain you setup isn't pointing to anything, it only exists, within your network

Comment: What's your ISP? Some ISPs intentionally block certain ports on residential networks so that they can sell you business class (and to cut some costs on their infrastructure).

Comment: @oldmud0 cox I believe. Not sure on my exact plan, I'd have to check.

Comment: @Ramhound oh okay. But my public ipv4 does not only exist within my network correct?

Comment: Port 80 is blocked. http://www.cox.com/residential/support/internet/article.cox?articleId=cacf82f0-6407-11df-ccef-000000000000

Comment: @oldmud0 oh darn. That would be it. Can I use a different port for my webserver or will that not work? Apache by default used 80.

Comment: You can use any port you like other than the ones on the list, and it'll work just fine. Be sure to update your port forwarding and web server configuration when you decide on a new port.